# Вопрос с установкой файлов с интернета

Tags: python, http, urllib

Я сделал некий код. Он будет устанавливать фотку с интернета. Как сделать директорию устанавливаемого файла, чтобы не было начала, но есть одна или в крайнем случае больше одной папки, которые 100% существуют. Должна быть подгрузка файла в папку, которая существует вне зависимости от диска.  Например: file\python\121.png

```
 def WebDownload(self):
        from urllib import request
        import sys
        myUrl = "https://games.mail.ru/hotbox/content_files/gallery/2019/10/02/c14b657b053d4b6394a990e4cbd1c70a.jpg"
        myFile = "D:\\Python\\121.png"
        try:
            request.urlretrieve(myUrl, myFile)
        except Exception:
            print("Ошибка!")
            print(sys.exc_info())
```

Comment: @Sergey Папка есть. Но не понятно в каком она диске. Перечитай ещё раз. Мне для автоустановки мода в игру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.makedirs) чтоб создать каталоги

```
import os
os.makedirs("file/python/", exist_ok=True)
```

Можно получить папку, в которой находится запущенный файл

```
import os, sys

def module_path():
    if hasattr(sys, "frozen"):
        return os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    return os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

А потом получаем путь относительно нашего запускаемого файла

```
myFile = os.path.join(module_path(), 'images' ,'121.png')
```

Comment: Попробуйте переписать вопрос по-русски и подробнее. Не в коментарии, а в самом вопросе. Ссылка править снизу

Comment: Спасибо за совет.

Comment: Сможете ответить?

Answer (score 0):

1) Создать папку

```
def createFolder(path):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
```

2) Скачать файл по ссылке и сохранить в нужную дерикторию

```
myUrl = "https://games.mail.ru/hotbox/content_files/gallery/2019/10/02/c14b657b053d4b6394a990e4cbd1c70a.jpg"
myFile = "D:\\Python\\121.png"

f = open(myFile, 'wb')
f.write(urlopen(myUrl).read())
f.close()
```